# Use a for loop to define a column in a dataframe based on adjacent columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
> head (DATA)
  N_b N_l X_ext    x.sqr_sum   e_1    e_2    e_3   e_4    e_5
1   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0
2   5   3    18       810      14.6   2.6   -9.4    0      0
3   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0
4   5   4    24       1440     21.8   9.8   -2.2  -14.2    0
5   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19
6   5   5    30       2250      29    17      5    -7     -19
```

I would like to add a new column R to the data frame such that it uses the following equation:
[image]

to find the maximum value for R for N_L values up to what it is given in the dataframe DATA above.
This means for rows 1 and 2 of the dataframe that N_L is equal to 3, the new added column selves for both:

```
DATA$R1 <- (1 / DATA$N_b) + ((DATA$X_ext * (DATA$e_1)) / DATA$x.sqr_sum)
DATA$R2 <- (2 / DATA$N_b) + ((DATA$X_ext * (DATA$e_1 + DATA$e_2)) / DATA$x.sqr_sum)
DATA$R3 <- (3 / DATA$N_b) + ((DATA$X_ext * (DATA$e_1 + DATA$e_2 + DATA$e_3)) / DATA$x.sqr_sum)
DATA$R <- max(DATA$R1, DATA$R2, DATA$R3)
```

I would also need to know which N_L value was responsible for the maximum value of R (which column has the maximum number for each row between R1, R2, etc.)

For rows 5 and 6 that have N_L = 5, there would be R1, R2, R3, R4, and R5, to choose the maximum from.

I want to write a for loop that would go through the values smaller and equal to N_L in each row and solve for R with the appropriate sum term. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the same computation to every row is something, what the function *apply* is made for. The outline is as follows:

1. Define your own function that computes R:

   ```
   compute.R <- function(x) {
      return( x["N_b"] / x["N_l"] + x["X_ext"]*sum()x[5:(4+x["N_l"])] / sum((1:x["N_b"])^2) )
   }
   ```
2. Call apply to compute all R values at once:

   ```
   R <- apply(DATA, FUN=compute.R, MAR=1)
   ```
3. Append the column to your data frame:

   ```
   DATA <- cbind(DATA, R=R)
   ```

Comment: My question is really regarding how to make the equation go through different values for N_l and choose the correct terns to sum for the e_ sum. I am not sure how to exactly do this with the function.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the complete function definition. Note that the argument passed by *apply* to the function is a vector onsisting of the single row just processed, not the entire data frame. in the sum in the denominator, I have started at position 5 because that is the position of *e_1*.